# How to remove sorting on a specific column in LWC lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I want to remove/hide sort for specific field Block__c

```
const Block = [    
{
        fieldName: 'parcelUrl',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {
                fieldName: Block
            },
            target: '_blank'
        },
        sortColumn: Block
    },
    {
        fieldName: Block__c
    },
    {
        fieldName: Block__c,
        sortable: "false"
    }

];`
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `false`, not `"false"`. In JavaScript, there are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values. Falsy values evaluate to false when used as a condition, and they are:

| Value | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | Null | The keyword null — the absence of any value. |
| undefined | Undefined | undefined — the primitive value. |
| false | Boolean | The keyword false. |
| NaN | Number | NaN — not a number. |
| 0 | Number | The Number zero, also including 0.0, 0x0, etc. |
| -0 | Number | The Number negative zero, also including -0.0, -0x0, etc. |
| 0n | BigInt | The BigInt zero, also including 0x0n, etc. Note that there is no BigInt negative zero — the negation of 0n is 0n. |
| "" | String | Empty string value, also including '' and ``. |
| document.all | Object | The only falsy object in JavaScript is the built-in document.all. |

Notice how `"false"` is not on that list. The only falsy string is the empty string (available as `''`, `""`, and ``` `` ```.

Make sure you pay attention to the data type you're using, because JavaScript, being a loosely typed language, will make a lot of assumptions for you.

Comment: With or without "", '' sorting is still visible for the column.